# can't take Screenshot using Ashot library with selenium

Tags: java, selenium, ashot

Hi I am using java with selenium and I need a screenshot and I am using Ashot to take a full webpage Screenshot below is my code

```
public static void saveFullPageScreenshot(String name) throws IOException {
        
        Screenshot screenshot = new AShot().shootingStrategy(ShootingStrategies.viewportPasting(1000))
                .takeScreenshot(driver);
        ImageIO.write(screenshot.getImage(), "PNG", new File(name));
        
    }
```

I call that function in the script

```
saveFullPageScreenshot("./src/test/resources/Reports/Images/tests.CBATTest/saveAsDraftReq/" + "Editdetailspage" + ".png");
```

I am getting can't create an ImageoutputStream!

below is the stack trace:-

```
  javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't create an ImageOutputStream!
    at java.desktop/javax.imageio.ImageIO.write(ImageIO.java:1553)
    at pageObjects.pages.CBATRequisitionPageObjects.createRequisitionEdit(CBATRequisitionPageObjects.java:391)
    at tests.CBATTest.saveAsDraftReq(CBATTest.java:509)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:132)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeMethod(TestInvoker.java:599)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethod(TestInvoker.java:174)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodRunner.runInSequence(MethodRunner.java:46)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker$MethodInvocationAgent.invoke(TestInvoker.java:822)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethods(TestInvoker.java:147)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:146)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:128)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:764)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:585)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:384)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:378)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:337)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:286)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:53)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:96)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1218)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1140)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1069)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1037)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
```

please help me with this Thanks in Advance